# Attribute table in R terra package?

Tags: raster, r, terra

I am interested in the `terra` R package as it appears to be a successor to the `raster` package that is being more actively developed than the `raster` package. But it seems like some features are missing.

For example I have an aggregated National Landcover Dataset raster in .GRD format.

If I call `x <- raster::raster('nlcd_agg.grd')` the resulting object has a slot `x@data@attributes` with the raster attribute table that includes the names of the land cover types corresponding to the integer values in the raster.

However if I call `x <- terra::rast('nlcd_agg.grd')` I cannot find that attribute table in the object nor do I see how to associate the object `x` with the attribute table of the raster.

I would like to be able to load the raster and have the associated attribute table with land cover type names and default plotting colors load as well. I understand that .GRD is a native format for the `raster` package but is there some way to achieve this with the `terra` or `stars` packages?

Here are two small files that can replicate the behavior (`nlcd_agg.grd` and the associated `nlcd_agg.gri`):

- [nlcd_agg.grd (Dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ifhwwt7zqu0pp8b/nlcd_agg.grd?dl=0)
- [nlcd_agg.gri (Dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s68ewb7odz74z75/nlcd_agg.gri?dl=0)

Comment: Any chance you can point us to the file or one that shows the same behaviour?

Comment: @Spacedman see my edit which also has some clarifications

Comment: Can't see a way. Perhaps worth an issue to the `terra` issue tracker. I'm holding off `terra` until it all works better than `raster` and I do a bit of teaching with categorical land use data...

Answer (score 3):

See the `cats` and `levels` methods. They are used to have rasters that behave like "factors".  The issues you describe have been fixed in terra 1.1-17 (on its way to CRAN). For now, what you can do is something along these lines:

```
library(raster)
f <- "nlcd_agg.grd"
r <- raster(f)

library(terra)
x <- rast(r)

# get the attributes
lev <- levels(r)[[1]]  
lev <- lev[, c("ID", "Land.Cover.Class")]
lev[,2] <- as.character(lev[,2])

x <- rast(r)
levels(x) <- lev
is.factor(x)
#[1] TRUE

x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 101, 121, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 3750, 3750  (x, y)
#extent      : 1394535, 1848285, 1722765, 2101515  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#name        : nlcd_2011_landcover_2011_edition_2014_03_31 
#min value   :                                Unclassified 
#max value   :                                             

# legend shows class names    
plot(x)
```

Labels are returned as cell values

```
x[c(7357, 5047, 7360, 9307)]
#  nlcd_2011_landcover_2011_edition_2014_03_31
#1                          Perennial Snow/Ice
#2                                  Open Water
#3                          Perennial Snow/Ice
#4                                Unclassified
```

And the categories are stored if you save the raster to a GeoTIFF

```
z <- writeRaster(x, "test.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
z
```

ch

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. The other piece of it is that the attribute table of the `.grd` raster also contains columns `Red`,`Green`,`Blue`, and `Opacity` that are used in the default `plot()` method to color the land cover classes appropriately. Is that feature implemented in terra?

Comment: No, and I had forgotten about that. See my expanded answer for a work-around. I will improve this

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. This may not be related, but I have not been able to write the raster to a GeoTIFF. I get a segfault error when I call `writeRaster(x, 'test.tif')`. I have tried it on GDAL 2.2.2 and 3.0.4 and get the same error: caught segfault, memory not mapped.

Comment: there is one other issue: if I want to go the `rats(x)` route, the `Land.Cover.Class` column is coerced from a factor to numeric. I worked around this by first coercing it to character before calling `rats(x) <- lev` but just wanted to call it to your attention.